# PHP Data Caching Function

Tags: php, caching

A want to cache datasets in PHP. i'm wondering if there is already a Caching Function in PHP, without any extentions/modules? I have no Access as a Admin to my Server:-(

Something simple like:

```
 saveString('Foo,Bar','Keyname',60);
 getString('Keyname')
```

Comment: [APCU](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php)

Comment: Iam not a Admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a Solution for String caching Function

```
define('cachepath','cache/');
$q=('StringKeyExists');

if(isString($q,30)){
     getString($q);
}else{
     $c=('Content to save');
    saveString($q,$c);
}



function isString($key,$time=60){
    $exp = 60 * $time; // 3600s = 1 hour
    $key=uniq($key);
    $file=@cachepath.$key;
    if(file_exists($file) &&( filectime($file) > time() - $exp)){
        return 1;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
function getString($key){
    $key=uniq($key);
    $file=@cachepath.$key;
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($file),1);


}
function uniq($str='',$nr=6){
    return substr(md5($str),0,$nr);
}
function saveString($key,$str=''){
    $key=uniq($key);
    $file=@cachepath.$key;
    return file_put_contents($file, json_encode($str));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example (simplified).

```
// write to cache file
$data = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
];

file_put_contents('cache.json', json_encode($data));

// read from cache file
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('cache.json'), true);
```

**Note**: Make sure that the cache file exists and that the php script has write access permission.